# Api key authentication

Tags: php, google-api

I want upload some files to my Google Drive account using a command line script.

I don't want use the PHP SDK so i am using cURL. There is my code:

```
$content = file_get_contents('foo.sql');
$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, sprintf(DRIVE_API_URL, DRIVE_API_KEY));
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    sprintf('Conent-Length: %s', strlen($content)),
    sprintf('Conent-Type: %s', 'application/sql')
]);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
$response = curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);
```

I am trying to authenticate using an API KEY generated from Google Console. And the URL where i am sending my request is:

> https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media&key=DRIVE_API_KEY

When i execute the request Google send a 401 response:

> {
>       "domain": "global",
>       "reason": "required",
>       "message": "Login Required",
>       "locationType": "header",
>       "location": "Authorization"    }

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE 1**

Now i am using the PHP SDK:

```
$client = new Google_Client([
    'developer_key' => 'MY_API_KEY'
]); 
$client->setScopes(implode(' ', [
Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY,
Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE ]));
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);


var_dump($service->files->listFiles());
```

And Google says:

> {
>       "domain": "global",
>       "reason": "insufficientFilePermissions",
>       "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."    }

Comment: It says you have to pass the key in the  `Authorizaton` header.

Comment: use PHP SDK) that's not that simple with google-api

Comment: @marekful is the same result ..

Comment: Have you read all details about Google authentication flows? Which one are you using? I guess you will have to use the provided api key in an OAuth2 flow to get an access / refresh token and pass that in the auth header. Use the SDK. Also, the API key is just sort of a username, you also need to pass a secret. You really should stick with the SDK until your understanding is less limited.